# regarding python list of strings

Tags: python

I want to check if a sentence is not in a list of sentences.So here I am using "not in" operator , but the problem is it is taking too much time for larger lists.

```
list_of_sentences = ["How are you" , "Who are you" , "Are you okay"]
string = "What about you?"
```

so if I want to check string is not in list I do:

```
if string not  in list_of_sentences:
       append the string to same list(list_of_sentences)
```

But it is not doing good if the there are Large number of strings to be searched and the size of "list_of_sentences" will grow with time.

So,is there any other which does this in a fastest way?

Comment: Use a set to decrease time complexity?